# How to group by multiple keys and values

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents where each document has a nestes field `outside` with two values:

```
_id: 9287645ztiu234jgk2j3g5jh,
outside: {
  temperature: 'low',            // 'low' or 'high'
  humidity: 'high',              // 'low' or 'high'
},
... some more fields
```

`temperature` and `humidity` can have value `low` or `high`

I want to count how many times `temperature: low`, `temperature: high`, `humidity: low`, `humidity: high` is present in each document of the collection, so the query result for e.g. 14 documents should look like this:

```
{
  temperatureLow: 2,
  temperatureHigh: 12,
  humidityLow: 8,
  humidityHigh: 6,
}
```

I tried a `$group` (as the only stage in the aggregation pipeline) like this:

```
$group: {
  _id: { temperature: '$outside.temperature', humidity: '$outside.humidity' },
  count: { $sum: 1 },
},
```

And this gives me these documents (EDITED, first post had wrong data):

```
{
    "_id": {
      "temperature": "high",
      "humidity": "high"
    },
    "count": 6
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "temperature": "high",
      "humidity": "low"
    },
    "count": 6
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "temperature": "low",
      "humidity": "low"
    },
    "count": 2
  }
```

How can it be combined into on document?

Comment: That's not possible. Are you showing your entire aggregation pipeline here? Give us a sample of your actual documents in your question.

Comment: @NeilLunn: I've edited my question, hope this makes it more clear. $group is the only stage in the pipeline. You can find a sample of a document at the top of my question.

Comment: Somthing isn't completely true here since it's not possible for that `$group` statement to return keys in the `_id` that are different to what you specify ( i.e You specify both but show output as one or the other ). Even if there was no matching property in the document, there would still be the two properties in the key but one or both would have a value of `null` in the output. So there is something else here that you are not showing.

Comment: It would be trivial to take the resulting documents and merge them into one - is this not an option?

Comment: You have been given an answer that is essentially the correct concept, but it is the results you are showing for the query you say you are running that are of concern. What you say you are running is equivalent to `{ "$group": { "_id": "$outside", "count" :{ "$sum": 1 } } }` except the keys from "outside" are declared explicitly. So if that is the actual document structure then you would get different outputs, and different counts to what you are reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. You need add `project` stage with the using `cont` operator before `group`:

```
{
    $project: {
        "temperatureLow": { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$outside.temperature", "low"] }, then: 1, else: 0 }}, 
        "temperatureHigh": { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$outside.temperature", "high"] }, then: 1, else: 0 }}, 
        "humidityLow": { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$outside.humidity", "low"] }, then: 1, else: 0 }}, 
        "humidityHigh": { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$outside.humidity", "high"] }, then: 1, else: 0 }}
    }
}, 
{
    $group: {
      _id: "result",
      "temperatureLow": {$sum: "$temperatureLow"},
      "temperatureHigh": {$sum: "$temperatureHigh"},
      "humidityLow": {$sum: "$humidityLow"},
      "humidityHigh": {$sum: "$humidityHigh"},
    }
},
```

**Update**

or as notes Neil Lunn I can use `cond` inside `sum` operator without `project` stage:

```
{
    $group: {
      _id: "result",
    "temperatureLow": {$sum: { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$outside.temperature", "low"] }, then: 1, else: 0 }}}, 
    "temperatureHigh": {$sum: { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$outside.temperature", "high"] }, then: 1, else: 0 }}}, 
    "humidityLow": {$sum:{ $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$outside.humidity", "low"] }, then: 1, else: 0 }}}, 
    "humidityHigh": {$sum:{ $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$outside.humidity", "high"] }, then: 1, else: 0 }}}          
    }
},
```

Comment: Actually you can just do that in a single `$group` stage with the `$cond` inside the `$sum`. Much faster. I'm just a little concerned that the OP's data is not actually structured like they are telling us.

Comment: the second version with only one `$group` stage works perfect! @all: thanks a lot for your help! (I've edited my original post, now it contains the right data)